# error accessing the uploaded file in jquery fileupload api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I have this code. Here, I'm using `fileupload` jquery api.

My HTML code

```
<span class="btn btn-danger select-button fileinput-button">
    <span>SELECT FILE</span>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file_image" />
    <input type="hidden" name="file_name" id="file_name" />
    <input type="hidden" name="file_type" id="file_type" />
</span>
<button type="button" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-danger select-button" onclick="enc_validation();" disabled="disabled">SUBMIT</button>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
'use strict';
var url = '<?php echo site_url('home/upload_file')?>';
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(<?php echo $accept_file_types; ?>)$/i,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            if (file.url) {
                $('#files').css('color','black').html(file.name);
                $('#btn-submit').attr('disabled',false);
                $('#new-files').val(file);
                $('#file_name').val(file.name);
                $('#file_type').val(file.type);
                $('#delete-area').html(file.deleteUrl);
            } else if (file.error) {
                $('#files').css('color','rgb(179,1,0)').html(file.error);
            }
        });
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
    },
    fail: function (e, data){console.log(data);
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('#files').css('color','green').html('Error');
        });         
    },
}).prop('disabled',     !$.support.fileInput).parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
function enc_validation() {
    alert($('#new-files').val());
}
```

As you can see in the code, I have attached the method of `fileupload` api while a file is chosen from the upload element. But, after that when the user clicks the submit button, I can't even alert the uploaded file. It just alerts "undefined". I don't know what's wrong. Here, in the `enc_validation()` method, all I'm doing is alerting the uploaded file and even that's giving me error. There might be some working of the `fileupload` api that I'm not aware of.
I might have overlooked something, but I am stuck here. I need help guys. And thanks in advance.

I know, there is no `#new-files` in the HTML, alerting `#fileupload` also does not work. All I want is the info of the file that is uploaded through the `#fileupload` element. How can I get that ?

Comment: I don't see id "new-files" in your HTML

Comment: Actually, this is code from an existing system. I also tried doing `alert($('#fileupload'));` but still, nothing. See my update.